# load content inside iframe using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have iframe that works at the server side :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 700px; background-color: #bacad3;" id="I1" name="I1" src="Page.aspx"></iframe>
```

and I change the content dynamically with this code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   I1.Attributes["src"] = "Page.aspx";
}
```

I want to implement it with ajax in the following way:

1. when user click out side of iframe dont postback page and change the src of iframe
2. I want to show the progress inside the progressupdatepanel

I mention it I dont want to run any postback just loading page inside the iframe with ajax by calling outside of iframe for example there is a button in the page and it is handled by update panel and it loads the content of other page inside the iframe.
Could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With onClientClick and mmke sure you return false to cancel the postback.

```
window.frames["frameName"].src = "http://example.com";
//or
document.getElementById("iframeId").src = "http://example.com";
```

If you are using runat=server you may need to use the client id

```
document.getElementById("<%= iframeId.ClientID %>").src = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is your answer was not complete that I can implement this thing if it is possible,please comment some refrences or sample link I dont have any background of onClientClick you just say onClientClick and making sure you return false to cancel the postback I use server side componants and I want to show the progress of loading page inside the iframe in the progress-updatepanel so you said but very short I couldn't understand

Comment: it has postback again, it doesn't work properly I want to remove postback during loading the new page inside iframe but now this one do nothing for me

Comment: MSDN Documentation is great http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is not possible using this method you can not remove postback it needs proxing method like google mail (gmail) when you click inbox it apears in the right without postback but we can not implement with this method.